# SIMPLE authentication is not enabled. Available:[TOKEN, KERBEROS] While getting spark context

Tags: authentication, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, kerberos, hadoop2

Installation Info :-

Hadoop version :- 2.6.5
Spark Version  :- 2.1.0
And Kerberos

I am trying to get the spark context in yarn mode with kerberos authentication but below exception.

Code :-

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Configuration conf = new Configuration();

        conf.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://localhost:9000");
        conf.set("hadoop.security.authentication", "kerberos");
        conf.set("hadoop.security.authorization", "true");

        UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(conf);

        System.out.println("Security enabled " + UserGroupInformation.isSecurityEnabled());


        SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Spark shell").setMaster("yarn");
        SparkSession  sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().config(sparkConf).getOrCreate();

        System.out.println(sparkSession.version() + " : " + sparkSession.sparkContext());
  }
```

Its prints security is enabled like:- Security enabled true

Exception :-

> org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: SIMPLE
>   authentication is not enabled.  Available:[TOKEN, KERBEROS]   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.ipc.RPCUtil.instantiateException(RPCUtil.java:53)

Please advise me to resolve this error.

Comment: Spark fetches Hadoop authentication tokens **before** even starting the Driver. You need to set the env variable `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` so that Hadoop libs find their XML config files.